# asyncFileUpload how to get new File Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asyncfileupload

asyncFileUpload how to get a new File Name after upload complete to save new name in database
asp.net c#

I have a form to fill in personal data and Upload own image 
Asyncfileupload used to select the picture and in the void AsyncFileUpload_UploadedComplete 
Save the file in new name

Now when the user ends of the mobilization of all form and presses the save button to save data , i save every thing in database I can not get the new name to save it.

Answer (score 0):

it is a property in the control. In you event handler check the FileName property. The following code assumes your are checking the file size to to intercept any oversized files.

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload_UploadedComplete(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    AsyncFileUpload upload = sender as AsyncFileUpload;
    if ((upload.PostedFile.ContentLength / 1000) <= 500)
    {
        string filename = upload.FileName;
        // save to the database here
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps :-)

Mike